# Setting up Asterisk Behavior (A dialing-queue, and three phones picking up calls from that queue)

Tags: asterisk, voip, server

I managed to setup Asterisk, FreePBX, and a VoIP Software Phone. I can make and receive calls through my Asterisk server, but now I need to setup the following behavior:

I want to have 3 software phones listening to a queue. The queue is constantly dialing 4 to 6 phone numbers simultaneously, and whenever someone picks up, that conversation is branched to one of the soft phones. When a phone number fails (i.e. no one picks up) it is removed from the queue. Also, if all 3 soft-phones are busy handling calls, the phone calls in the queue are dropped, and the queue stops dialing until a software phone is available again. The queue will work its way down a list of phone numbers. I should be able to add to this list on-the-fly. That is, during the course of 10 phone calls, I should be able to add say 5 new phone numbers to the queue without having to restart the program or rebuild anything (I am okay with programming scripts. I know javascript, C#, php, and can handle linux commands). How might I go about doing this? Or at least, where is a good place to start?

Answer (score 0):

Look here

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/ACD_id285928.html

But better read entire book.